# C# WPF Listview updating

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview like the picture below. As you can se I have one column called **Time**. 
I want to know how I can update the time automatically.

For example the time of Flight Code ABC123 should after 1 minute change from 3 minutes to 4 minutes.

[image: Flight ListView]

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [dispatch timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) and perform a record update every minute

That's what I would do

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem with events or delegates?

Comment: Sure, but what event are you planning to tie into.  If you need it every minute, I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

[Big smart ViewModels, dumb Views, and any model, the best MVVM approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857820/big-smart-viewmodels-dumb-views-and-any-model-the-best-mvvm-approach) contains the code for WPF app where ViewModel (and View bound to it) is updated by timer. It is there by every 1 sec (1000 ms)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** *wasn't happy with the idea of invalidating the binding every minute (that could be completely unfounded, and invalidating every minute is fine, I don't know), so came up with a 'purer' implementation that sets the content directly, left the original in for reference though:*

You could look to do it through an `AttachedBehaviour`, the below should be able to get you started:

```
public static class TimeAgoBehaviour {

    static Lazy<DispatcherTimer> LazyTimer = new Lazy<DispatcherTimer>(() => {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) };
        timer.Start();
        return timer;
    });
    static ConcurrentDictionary<int, EventHandler> Events = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, EventHandler>();

    public static DateTime GetTimeAgo(ContentControl obj) {
        return (DateTime)obj.GetValue(TimeAgoProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTimeAgo(ContentControl obj, DependencyProperty value) {
        obj.SetValue(TimeAgoProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeAgoProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TimeAgo",
        typeof(DateTime), typeof(TimeAgoBehaviour),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.UtcNow, OnTimeAgoChanged));

    private static void OnTimeAgoChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var newDate = (DateTime)e.NewValue;

        EventHandler oldEvent;
        if (Events.TryRemove(sender.GetHashCode(), out oldEvent)) {
            LazyTimer.Value.Tick -= oldEvent;
        }

        if (DateTime.MinValue == newDate) {
            return;
        }

        var doUpdate = new EventHandler((s, args) => {
            ContentControl control = sender as ContentControl;
            control.Content = TimeAgoConverter.GetTimeAgo(newDate);
        });

        doUpdate(sender, new EventArgs());

        Events.TryAdd(sender.GetHashCode(), doUpdate);
        LazyTimer.Value.Tick += doUpdate;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Label local:TimeAgoBehaviour.TimeAgo="{Binding InitialisedDate}" />
```

*Below is the original response:*

---

You could look to do it through an `AttachedBehaviour`, which invalidates the binding every minute, causing it to be re-evaluated, the below works, as a starting point extend where you need to:

Code:

```
public static class PropertyToInvalidateBehaviour {

    static Lazy<DispatcherTimer> LazyTimer = new Lazy<DispatcherTimer>(() => {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) };
        timer.Start();
        return timer;
    });
    static ConcurrentDictionary<int, EventHandler> Events = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, EventHandler>();

    public static DependencyProperty GetPropertyToInvalidate(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (DependencyProperty)obj.GetValue(PropertyToInvalidateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPropertyToInvalidate(DependencyObject obj, DependencyProperty value) {
        obj.SetValue(PropertyToInvalidateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyToInvalidateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PropertyToInvalidate",
      typeof(DependencyProperty), typeof(PropertyToInvalidateBehaviour),
      new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyToInvalidateChanged));

    private static void OnPropertyToInvalidateChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var propertyToInvalidate = e.NewValue as DependencyProperty;

        EventHandler oldEvent;
        if (Events.TryRemove(e.Property.GetHashCode(), out oldEvent)) {
            LazyTimer.Value.Tick -= oldEvent;
        }

        if (null == propertyToInvalidate) {
            return;
        }

        var doUpdate = new EventHandler((s, args) => {
            BindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(sender as DependencyObject, propertyToInvalidate);
            binding.UpdateTarget();
        });

        Events.TryAdd(e.Property.GetHashCode(), doUpdate);
        LazyTimer.Value.Tick += doUpdate;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=InitialisedDate, Converter={StaticResource cnvTimeAgo}}" local:PropertyToInvalidateBehaviour.PropertyToInvalidate="Label.Content" />`
```