# WPF Binding Command

Tags: wpf, binding, command

I have following checkbox:

```
<dxe:CheckEdit Margin="2,0" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedContact.isMajor,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource CheckBoxNullToFalse}}">More than 18</dxe:CheckEdit>
```

This is what i want to achieve: when the user clicks on the check box, i want to call a function but also assign the isMajor field.

The only way i see how to do this is to bind to a command that will perform both operations

Is there a more straightforward way ?
Thanks
John

Comment: What is isMajor Field, another check box or some field in your database ?

Answer (score 1):

Make `isMajor` a property rather than a field, and call a method in the setter

```
private bool _isMajor;
public bool IsMajor
{
    get { return _isMajor; }
    set
    {
        _isMajor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsMajor");
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, using a Command is the first thing that occurred to me. I assume that `dxe:CheckEdit` is some CheckBox variant - you might find a `ToggleButton` useful, as an alternative, depending on what behavior you're looking for.

I'm not sure what you mean by "straightforward" (least code, easiest to understand, etc.), but binding `IsChecked` to an `isMajor` property (as per @Thomas Levesque) and binding to a Command ([Relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862570/relaycommand-in-wpf) or [Delegate](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html), for example) to call the function provides a clean way to do both things that you want without introducing side-effects into your code, as you would if you called the function from a property setter or your `Converter`, for example, that wouldn't be obvious to other developers. Or to you, when you return to maintain this a year from now. :)