# Wpf DataTemplate Event Handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, datatemplate

I have extended ListView class and created two `DataTemplate` for it in the separate Resource file. My question is how I can add event handlers for the `Checkbox` (and other items) in the `DataTemplate`?

MyListView.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
    public class MyListView : ListView
    {
        public enum ListMode
        {
            List, ListCheck
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "Mode",
            typeof(ListMode),
            typeof(MyListView),
            new PropertyMetadata(ListMode.List)
        );

        public ListMode Mode
        {
            get { return (ListMode)GetValue(ModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ModeProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

MyListViewItem.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
    public class MyListViewItem:Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyListViewItem),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
        );

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "IsChecked",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(MyListViewItem),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false)
        );

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate_List">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate_ListCheck">
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyListView}">
        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="Mode" Value="List">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate_List}"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="Mode" Value="ListCheck">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate_ListCheck}"/>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Why would want to create a custom control for achieving the same? This can be done easily by using a `DataTemplateSelector` without modifying the control.

Answer (score 1):

Your question refers to `Event handlers` and the use of them in Resource files.  Access to the code-behind cannot be expressed directly in `XAML` stored in resource files.

While you are able to do the following in the XAML of a UserControl,

```
    <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_OnClick"/>
```

this is simply not possible when the style is detached in a separate resource directory.

This is where the `ICommand` interface becomes useful to trigger, usually, on the ViewModel but can also be used to trigger code-behind.  The syntax then becomes (if you are looking to trigger code-behind):-

```
   <CheckBox Command="{Binding CheckBoxClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyListView'}}"/>
```

This would allow you to trigger code in your `MyListView` class if you:-

1. Add a property called `CheckBoxClickedCommand` to your `MyListView` class
2. Add the supporting interface for `ICommand` on that property of that class

It is common to use the `RelayCommand` implementation so you can supply Lambda Expressions to simplify the implementation.  A quick search on [RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862570/how-can-i-use-the-relaycommand-in-wpf) will give you some guidance.

This all sounds good until you find out that only certain controls (e.g. `Button`, `Checkbox`, `RadioButton`) implement the `Command` pattern as standard.

Luckily since Blend 3 we now have more scope to use the `ICommand` pattern using Behaviours, again something you might want to research.

```
  <CheckBox Command="{Binding CheckBoxClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckBoxMouseEnterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Checkbox>
```

Here other events such as `MouseEnter` can be used  to fire off an `ICommand` call.  This also means other controls that did not support the `Command=` property can also call the code-behind.