# How to distinguish which button was being clicked from a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a user control with two buttons (Add, Delete). When accessed from the main window, how do I know which button were being clicked?

`btnAdd` had a method while `btnDelete` has another method that should be invoked.

Comment: You can tell from which method gets called. The XAML should tell you which event gets called for which button.

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate Command for button `add` and `delete` in MainWindow

And you can bind your command in userControl like this:

```
<Button Command={Binding AddCommand}/>
```

and set the `datacontext` of `Mainwindow` to itself inside XAML or in a constructer

```
this.datacontext = this;
```

For more information on how to create Command see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862570/how-can-i-use-the-relaycommand-in-wpf) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1052346/ICommand-Interface-in-WPF)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could cast the sender argument in the event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button.Name == "btnAdd ")
    {
        //add button was clicked...
    }
    else if (button.Name == "btnDelete")
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
<Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" />
<Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Comment: It makes no sense to assign the same handler to two different buttons if you just want to do completely different things when either is clicked.

Comment: You may not want to do *completely* different things. It is hard to say what the OP wants. But casting the sender argument is a way to  "know which button were being clicked".

Comment: The two *different handlers* can both call some of the same methods (or the same methods with different arguments) if their behavior is similar.  The point remains that if you want to do different things when different buttons are clicked you should give them different handlers, not give them the same handler, then check the button, so  you can then go do two different things.